# How to have Django model fields with possibility of multiple entry/input?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django models fields and i want one of the fields with multiple entry or input. is it possible using *args? Below is my models and the "cc" fields is the one that I want to have multiple input and using def save function, but no avail. thank you in advance for possible advise.

## models.py:

```
class Rtana(models.Model):
    rsc_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
    rsc = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    cc = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    def save(self,*args):
        super(Rtana,self).save(*args)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.rsc_name , self.rsc)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("app7_cbv:details",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: You make an extra model that has a `ForeignKey` to `Rtana` and extra fields for each "entry".

Comment: Well it looks like more of a conflation of the database layer with the ORM. First decide what you want at the database layer. Probably another table as Willem says. Possibly a JSON Field or comma-separated string or something. But only once that's figured out does it make sense to talk about saving data to that field. You can't save a list to a CharField if that's what you're asking.

Comment: thank you Sir's for the input. will closely look into it using JSON and DB side.  will explore the JSONField on django. thanks again.